# How do i decide if to quit or not with a message from my application using shutdown hook?

Tags: java, android

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

In the //do your stuff part how do i add there a message like "Are you sure about closing without saving all data ?" and decide yes or no so this message will be show on my device.

And another sub question this method will run automatic when i clode/quit my app on my device ? I want that this will happen only when i quit my app on my device.

Comment: First, AFAIK, this is not called. Your process is simply terminated. Second, you cannot interrupt the shutdown process here. Third, you will not be in the foreground when your process is terminated, and so it will be *very* inappropriate to pop up some sort of modal confirmation dialog in the middle of whatever the user is doing. "I want that this will happen only when i quit my app on my device" -- users do not "quit" apps. They leave them (e.g., press HOME), and those apps' processes eventually are terminated to free up system RAM.

Comment: You should use one of the `Activity`s life cycle methods like `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`

Comment: From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)): *Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that your code is run.* ***Instead, you should use the most appropriate lifecycle notification***

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're looking in the wrong direction. I'd start with the following:

1. Identify a place in your app where you want to prompt user for confirmation: `Activity`, `Fragment`. Example: you can show this dialog when user is going back from specific Activity
2. Use one of callbacks like `onBackPressed()` in Activity to present a dialog.

Also if you decide to use lifecycle methods be advised that `Activity` lifecycle is complicated and you don't have control over it.

Comment: I want the prompt message will be show when the user click on the device the back button arrow looks like <| or if the middle button looks like O circle then when the app is closing show the message or without showing the message just dispose and quit everything so next time i run the program it will start from the start everything is reseted. In my case it's lg g3 device if it's matter. I have MainActivity with atimer method and when the user on the device click to close the app i want to show or not show the message and reset and stop/dispose everything.

Comment: @ShimritHadadi well, there's really no such thing in Android as "close the app". I'd suggest you take a look at Android app and Activity lifecycle in dev docs.